# ASP.Net Core 2.2 Web API Queued background tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to implement a search functionality using queued background task, but I have problem with returning the value of the queued task.

I have following 2 APIs:

1. SearchUserAsync(SearchParameter parameter)
2. GetSearchResultAsync(int id)

SearchUserAsync API registers a background task in the queue that will search for the use the user based on SearchParameter but in the meanwhile it will return the HTTP 202(Accepted) which indicated that the request has been accepted with GetSearchResultAsync API's URL with id of queued task in response header("Location") to get the result later on.

Then the client calls GetSearchResultAsync API with **id(probably the id of queued task)** and gets the result of search operation if the operation has been executed.

Now, I'm having difficult in understanding how to assign id to the queued task and how to store the result of the queued task so I could access it later on when GetSearchResultAsync API is called.

I've tried to understand documentation on following links but could not grasp the overall concept.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice
- https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/805

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that you can successfully queue the task to the background, what you need is to generate a GUID that you 1) return to the client and 2) use as a key for the result of the operation once it is executed. The background task, upon completion, can add the GUID (as key) and the result (as value) to a dictionary structure (probably in memory or in some persistent storage). Another endpoint will simply try retrieving that value (based on the GUID that the client sends) from the structure where all results are kept.

Comment: Would not recommend doing this with out any knowing exactly what will happen when things started. Try using something like [hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)